# mysql database how to deal with fields that contains multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, select, multiple-value

i have MYSQL database  where a table have a field that contains multiple values in each cell. where these values are a foreign key of another table.

**inspection_date:**

- siteID (primary key)
- employeeID(foreign key)
- inspectionDate

where the emplyee field will have multiple values  be cause more than one employee had done the inspection.

**employee**

- employeeID(primary key)
- employeeName

can anyone help me  to use **select query**

## mysql :

```
$query_site_location =$wpdb->get_results("select DISTINCT 
                      l.siteID,
                      l.locationName, 
                      n.inspectionDate,
                      s.employeeID
                       from site_location l
                       LEFT    
                       JOIN inspection_info n
                       on l.siteID = n.siteID
                       LEFT  
                       JOIN employee s
                       on n.employeeID = s.employeeID");
```

the result must be in the field of  employee  **(6-7)** for the first row

Comment: The standard solution to "deal with" this problem is to design your datatables and relations so that you're not storing multiple values in a single cell.... it's always bad design, and creates many. many problems. normalize your data tables

Comment: What data you want to get?

Comment: It sounds like there's a one-to-many relationship between "inspection_info" entity and "employee" entity. Storing multiple values in a column flies in the face of entity-relationship modeling and relational database theory. Don't do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220390/how-to-model-one-to-many-relationship-in-database

Comment: guys i have this scenario where 3 employees do an inspection in  5/2/2017 
how can i store these data  based on the database

Comment: so can i use the inspectionDate as a foreign key in the employee entity?

Comment: 1. What is the problem? I can see no answerable question here ("How to deal...?" => "Just parse it"). 2. "How can i store [this] data?" => See the Spencer's link.

Answer (score 0):

A THIS relation is many to many  we must create a third entity in order to handle the primary keys of both tables.

**employee:**

```
employeeID(PRIMARY KEY)
employeeName
```

**inspection_info:**

```
inspectionID(PRIMARY KEY)
inspectionDate
employeeID
```

**inspection_site:**

```
inspectionID(PRIMARY KEY)

siteID(PRIMARY KEY)
```